# Sound from new brakes

Tags: brake-rotor

I recently changed my both front brake pads and rotors, but after two days it started to make sound at very slow speed less than 5 km/h like a complete stop. It only sounds when reaching complete stop. What it could be? Is there any solution for this.

Comment: Did you use all the brake clips? Did you put high temp brake grease to the slider pins and back plate of the pads?

Comment: I went to the same place and they cleaned both rotors and pads with a break clear and still have the issue, they say no problem with brake, 

Comment: So, either the brake pads are high performance pads and require break in, in order to function properly or they are not installed properly if they are OEM spec.